# How do I attach a debugger to native code of a release build in a react-native Android app?

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react-native app that's crashing in native code but only on Android release mode builds. I know it's possible to debug native code in Android Studio in debug mode. How do I attach a debugger to native code with Android Studio in release mode?

Comment: alternatively, you can add alerts to be displayed on actions or screens where the crash is supposedly going to happen.

Comment: I don't quite understand. The crash is happening randomly in the Java code of react-native. How would I go about adding logging or alerts to the internal Java parts of react-native then running a release build with those additions?

Answer (score 0):

This is the library i use to report production bugs and crashes : [bugsnag-](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-react-native) .Its pretty good , you get a report of all the errors which your users face and also along with devices id and mobile type.Its integrtaion is pretty simple.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts.

Comment: I'm already using a similar product, Instabug (which is fantastic!), but unfortunately it's not giving me all the information I need. I get a stack trace for this error but it's just internal react-native stuff. I need to attach a debugger, hit a breakpoint, and see what the data is inside that react-native Java code during the crash to diagnose it.